# API needs to call a function that the user implements

Tags: c++, design-patterns, interface

I am trying to create a C++ API but this API need to query the user of the API for information.

For example, I am going to process all mouse input, but when I get a left click event I need to ask the user if the object that was clicked on is one they wish to be interacted with.  If it is, then actions will be taken, if not then I will ignore the input.

So in my API when I get a mouse left click I need to call a function, whose functionality is dependent on the user of the API, and evaluate based on the return of that function.

Is there a design pattern for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design pattern you're looking for is [Callback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29).

Basically how this works is as follows:

1. You declare a pointer to a function.  This declaration will take in to account both the return value and the parameters (if any) of the function to be called.
2. You provide a mechanism for the client to "register" a function to be called, where the client passes in a function pointer and perhaps some other info.
3. When an event happens that you need to notify your client of, you call the registered function, passing in any pertinent data.